# Wanted: acts_as_nested_set, AJAX drag and drop tutorial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

Can anyone suggest a tutorial or sample code that implements a nested set (or similar ordered tree structure) with associated Javascript that facilitates drag and drop? I'm looking for both the display code (view) as well as the AJAX backend controller which writes the tree to the database on change.

I want it to represent a multi-layer menu where the ordering and depth of items is important.

Answer (score 2):

After much searching I found [this online example](http://www.artweb-design.de/2008/5/30/scriptaculous-sortabletree), written by Sven Fuchs, which does 90% of what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
http://www.justinball.com/2009/01/18/heirarchies-trees-jquery-prototype-scriptaculous-and-acts_as_nested_set/

Answer (score -2):

Something like this you really don't wanna be slapping a jquery plugin for. If you can't find anything out there it's time to make yourself an espresso and dive right into the code yourself :)

Use other -- more mature -- code out there as a sample point, but write it yourself and it will really suit your project the best. Looking for front-end and back-end code together is real tough too... unless you want something from a blog post that might be titled something like "30 jquery plugins to AJAXify your website" and you want crap PHP code. (In this case it appears that you want RoR)

This might not be of much assistance to you, but it's what I would do.

I'm particularly anti-jquery-plugins anyway... even if it does the job you want. A lot of that code is bloat. Plus I tend not to trust other people :)

Answer (score -2):

I have used  [www.dhtmlgoodies.com](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com) 's drag-drop-folder tree to do this. it's not the latest most up-to-date mootools/jquery/yourfavoriteframework javascript, but you don't have to look at that, it does it's job nicely as a component, and comes with a nice set of images.

I created a little mootools 1.1 wrapper class:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function()
    {
        document.Treeview = new TreeView();
    });


TreeView = new Class({

    initialize: function()
    {
        treeObj = new JSDragDropTree();
        treeObj.setTreeId('treeview');
        treeObj.initTree();
        treeObj.showHideNode(true, 'node0');
        $$('.hiddennode').each(function(elm) { elm.setStyle('display','none'); });
        this.currentItem = false;
    },

    saveValues: function() 
    {
        saveString = treeObj.getNodeOrders();
        new Ajax('./menuitem/save', {postBody: 'order='+saveString, onComplete:function(){window.Growl(this.transport.responseText)}, multiple:false}).request();
    },

    addItem: function()
    {
        new Ajax('./menuitem/add', {update:'editPanel'}).request();     
    },

    loadMenuItem: function(id)
    {
        this.currentItem = id;
        new Ajax('./menuitem/edit/'+id, {update:'editPanel', onComplete:function(){new ScrollDing('editPanel');}}).request();
    },

    removeItem: function()
    {
        if(!this.currentItem)
        {
            alert('please select a menu item to delete.');
        }
        else
        {
        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this menu item?'))
        { 
            // multiple: true is my little extension to mootools's Ajax class. 
        // It expects a JSON object with keys corresponding to element ID's
        // and updates their innerHTML
            new Ajax('./menuitem/delete/'+this.currentItem, {multiple:true}).request();
            this.currentItem = false;
        }
        }
    }

});
```

There's a PHP class that does the basic setup. I've simplified some things for the example, but this should get you started. ofcourse you will have to adjust it to use RoR :-P

```
/**
 * 
 * @package Pork
 * @author SchizoDuckie
 * @copyright SchizoDuckie 2008
 */
class TreeMenu
{
    private  $menuItems, $output;
    function __construct()
    {
        global $db;

        $input =  $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY intparent, intOrder");
        for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($input); $i++)
        {
            $array = $input[$i];
            $this->menuItems[ $array->intParent ][ ] = $array;
        }
    }

    function hasSubItems($node)
    {
        return (array_key_exists($node, $this->menuItems) && sizeof($this->menuItems[$node]) > 0) ? true : false;
    } 

    function displaytree($start=0, $noSiblings=false)
    {
        $output .= "<ul>";
        for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($this->menuItems[$start]); $i++)
        {

            $item = $this->menuItems[$start][$i];
            $siblings = ($noSiblings) ? "  " : '';
            $output .=  "<li id='node{$item->ID_Menu}'{$siblings}><a href='#' onclick='Treeview.loadMenuItem({$item->ID_Menu});return false;'>{$item->strMenuItem}</a>";
            if ($this->hasSubItems($item->ID_Menu))
            {
                $output .= $this->displayTree($item->ID_Menu, $noSiblings);
            }
            $output .=  "</li>";
        }       
       $output .=   "</ul>";
       return($output);
    }

    function getTreeInnerHTML()
    {
        return("<li id='node0' noDrag='true' noSiblings='true'><a href='#' onclick='return false'>Root</a>{$this->displaytree()}</li>");


    function display()
    {
        global $_TPL;

        $_TPL['styles'][] = './includes/drag-drop-folder-tree.css';
        $_TPL['scripts'][]= './includes/drag-drop-folder-tree.js';
        $_TPL['scripts'][]= './includes/pork.foldertree.js';

        return ("<div id='treebuttons'>
            <input type='button' onclick='Treeview.saveValues()' value='Save order'>
            <input type='button' onclick='Treeview.addItem()' value='Add'>
            <input type='button' onclick='Treeview.removeItem()' value='Remove'>
        </div>
        <ul id='treeview'>{$this->getTreeInnerHTML()}</ul>
        <div id='msgDiv'></div>

        <div id='editPanel'></div>
        ");
    }

}
```

usage:

```
$tv = new TreeView();
$_TPL['menu'] = $tv->display();
```

Here's also the examples for changing the order and what the add and edit and delete functions do (simplified ofcourse). JsObject is just a wrapper with a display function and __get and __set function that die()'s with a json_encoded array. Very handy for ajax requests ;)

```
<?
global $_URI;

switch ($_URI[0])
{
    case 'menuitem':
        switch ($_URI[1])
        {
            case 'add':
                $item = new menuItem();
                die($item->displayEditor('Add Menu Item', "multiple:true"));
            break;
            case 'edit':
                $item = new menuItem($_URI[2]);
                $_SESSION['currentMenuItem'] = $_URI[2];
                die($item->displayEditor('Edit MenuItem', 'multiple:true'));
            break;
            case 'delete':
                $item = new menuItem($_URI[2]);
                $item->deleteYourSelf();
                $js = new jsObject();
                $js->editPanel = 'Menu Item '.$item->menuItem.' has been deleted.';

                $menu = new Menu();
                $js->treeview = $menu->getTreeInnerHTML();
                $js->script = "document.Treeview = new TreeView();";    
                $js->display();
            break;
            case 'save':
            $items = explode(",",$_POST['order']);
            for($i=0;$i<sizeof($items);$i++)
            {
                $tokens = explode("|",$items[$i]);
                $db->query("update menu set intParent='{$tokens[1]}', intOrder='{$i}' where ID_Menu='{$tokens[0]}'");
            }
            die('Saved the new order!');
        break;
        }
    break;
}

?>
```

There you have it, one tutorial with readable, self-explanatory code. It's not RoR, and not Prototype, but this should get you started right?